# Doxygen - Variable documented but not defined when it really is?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have the following

```
    static uint8_t sreadBuf [SERIAL_BUF_SIZE]  __attribute__ ((section (".data.$SDRAM_B0_HEAP"))) = {0};
```

The top of the file has the appropriate doxygen stuff

```
 /**
 * \file blah.cpp
 * \brief blah implmentation
*/
```

Doxygen throws the following warning: `warning: documented symbol 'static uint8_t sreadBuf' was not declared or defined.`

Other static variables (and buffers) in the same file have no issues, doxygen doesn't complain and they are all declared the same way (they even have documentation strings).

Here is the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`:

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.10.0 (ebc57c6dd303a980bd19dd74b8b61c8f3f5180ca)
PROJECT_NAME           = "redacted"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 1234
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "redacted"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./doxygen
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
INPUT                  = ./source
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.pyw \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f95 \
                         *.f03 \
                         *.f08 \
                         *.f18 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf \
                         *.ice
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = ./source/ArduinoJson-v7.0.0.hpp \
                         ./source/lwipopts.h \
                         ./source/FreeRTOSConfig.h \
                         ./source/LICENSES.h \
                         ./source/semihost_hardfault.c
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = *.bak
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2
HAVE_DOT               = YES
```

Why is doxygen saying the symbol is documented but not declared or defined? It very clearly is declared and defined, and gcc throws no fits. If anything it's not documented.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Just post the result of `doxygen -x Doxyfile` which gives the settings different from the default settings. Post a, small, complete example showing the issue.

Comment: @albert updated, but in the process of building the complete example I got different results, which pointed me to the answer I actually posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the root cause:
`__attribute__ ((section (".data.$SDRAM_B0_HEAP")))` was confusing doxygen. Even though it goes against from what I've seen in the standards, moving the `__attribute__` section before the definition seems to make doxygen happy.

```
/**
 * \brief Upper layer serial read buffer
 */
static __attribute__ ((section (".data.$SDRAM_B0_HEAP"))) uint8_t sreadBuf 
[SERIAL_BUF_SIZE] = {0};
```

Works

Comment: `__attribute__` is not a standard term, it is a GNU extension. See for this also the chapter in the doxygen manual about preprocessing (file:///D:/Program%20Files/doxygen/html/preprocessing.html) and search in this chapter for `__attribute__`.